# How to manually set seed value as 1000 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-schema, auto-increment

I am using MySQL 5. I need to set the seed value as 1000 for my auto increment field.
How can I set it?

Answer (score 15):

To set when creating your table:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx(...) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

To set after creating the table:

```
ALTER TABLE xxx AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

Answer (score 11):

If the table already exists, you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

But make sure the highest value in the auto_increment column is less than 1000.

If you are creating a new table, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```