# How to edit 'Extra' value of a column in sql table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I initially added a primary key column named id in my table, which was an auto-increment column - meaning it has `AUTO_INCREMENT` in it's 'Extra' value

[image]

Now the id column's value starts from 1. I want it to start from 100000 instead of 1 - how do I change the configuration of the id column to make it start the column data from 100000? What should the SQL query look like? Please guide... Thanks!

Comment: Read this post : [how-to-manually-set-seed-value-as-1000-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536065/how-to-manually-set-seed-value-as-1000-in-mysql) And This:[example-auto-increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Can I ask why?.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `alter table xxxxx auto_increment=xxx;` statement:

```
create table test(id int primary key auto_increment);
alter table test  auto_increment=10000;
insert test values(default);
select * from test;
-- result set
10000
```